# Circular objects rotate angle detection

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect angle difference between two circular objects, which be shown as 2 image below.

I'm thinking about rotate one of image with some small angle. Every time one image rotated, SSIM between rotated image and the another image will be calculated. The angle with maximum SSIM will be the angle difference.

But, finding the extremes is never an easy problem. So my question is: Are there another algorithms (opencv) can be used is this case?

IMAGE #1
[image: Master image]

IMAGE #2
[image]

**EDIT:**

Thanks @Micka, I just do the same way he suggest and remove black region like @Yves Daoust said to improve processing time. Here is my final result:

ORIGINAL IMAGE
[image: image 1]
ROTATED + SHIFTED IMAGE
[image: image 2]

Comment: Try a Hough Circular Transform. Once you've identified the circles, you can rotate them about the common center using something like match filtering to determine the best rotation.

Comment: what's the result for this image pair? Is the angle difference 42° in this example?

Comment: @Micka yes, the result must be around 42°.

Comment: @MadPhysicist by rotate one of them step by step, it is really complicated to find the best angle. Can feature matching detect angle of the rotation in this case?

Comment: *don't* rotate the image step by step. that's wasteful. hough circles are a necessary starting step (or something else to get a hold of the circle), **but then** you need a polar transform. then the pictures only differ in translation along one axis. estimation of the translation can be dealt with by a convolution.

Comment: and if you need to account for scale additionally, do a log-polar transform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

1. detect circles (for the example I assume circle is in the image center and radius is 50% of the image width)
2. unroll circle images by polar coordinates
3. make sure that the second image is fully visible in the first image, without a "circle end overflow"
4. simple template matching

Result for the following code:

```
min: 9.54111e+07
pos: [0, 2470]
angle-right: 317.571
angle-left: -42.4286
```

I think this should work quite well in general.

```
int main()
{
    // load images
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/circleAngle/circleAngle1.jpg");
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/circleAngle/circleAngle2.jpg");

    // generate circle information. Here I assume image center and image is filled by the circles.
    // use houghCircles or a RANSAC based circle detection instead, if necessary
    cv::Point2f center1 = cv::Point2f(image1.cols/2.0f, image1.rows/2.0f);
    cv::Point2f center2 = cv::Point2f(image2.cols / 2.0f, image2.rows / 2.0f);
    float radius1 = image1.cols / 2.0f;
    float radius2 = image2.cols / 2.0f;

    cv::Mat unrolled1, unrolled2;
    // define a size for the unrolling. Best might be to choose the arc-length of the circle. The smaller you choose this, the less resolution is available (the more pixel information of the circle is lost during warping)
    cv::Size unrolledSize(radius1, image1.cols * 2);

    // unroll the circles by warpPolar
    cv::warpPolar(image1, unrolled1, unrolledSize, center1, radius1, cv::WARP_POLAR_LINEAR);
    cv::warpPolar(image2, unrolled2, unrolledSize, center2, radius2, cv::WARP_POLAR_LINEAR);

    // double the first image (720° of the circle), so that the second image is fully included without a "circle end overflow"
    cv::Mat doubleImg1;
    cv::vconcat(unrolled1, unrolled1, doubleImg1);

    // the height of the unrolled image is exactly 360° of the circle
    double degreesPerPixel = 360.0 / unrolledSize.height;

    // template matching. Maybe correlation could be the better matching metric
    cv::Mat matchingResult;
    cv::matchTemplate(doubleImg1, unrolled2, matchingResult, cv::TemplateMatchModes::TM_SQDIFF);

    double minVal; double maxVal; cv::Point minLoc; cv::Point maxLoc;
    cv::Point matchLoc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(matchingResult, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());

    std::cout << "min: " << minVal << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pos: " << minLoc << std::endl;

    // angles in clockwise direction:
    std::cout << "angle-right: " << minLoc.y * degreesPerPixel << std::endl;
    std::cout << "angle-left: " << minLoc.y * degreesPerPixel -360.0 << std::endl;
    double foundAngle = minLoc.y * degreesPerPixel;
    
    // visualizations:
    // display the matched position
    cv::Rect pos = cv::Rect(minLoc, cv::Size(unrolled2.cols, unrolled2.rows));
    cv::rectangle(doubleImg1, pos, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    // resize because the images are too big
    cv::Mat resizedResult;
    cv::resize(doubleImg1, resizedResult, cv::Size(), 0.2, 0.2);
    
    cv::resize(unrolled1, unrolled1, cv::Size(), 0.2, 0.2);
    cv::resize(unrolled2, unrolled2, cv::Size(), 0.2, 0.2);

    double startAngleUpright = 0;
    cv::ellipse(image1, center1, cv::Size(100, 100), 0, startAngleUpright, startAngleUpright + foundAngle, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1, 0);

    cv::resize(image1, image1, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    cv::imshow("image1", image1);

    cv::imshow("unrolled1", unrolled1);
    cv::imshow("unrolled2", unrolled2);

    cv::imshow("resized", resizedResult);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    
}
```

This is how the intermediate images and results look like:

unrolled image 1 / unrolled 2 / unrolled 1 (720°) / best match of unrolled 2 in unrolled 1 (720°):

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Yep, that's the way I would do it (but without all this black area).

Comment: drawn green rectangle was too small (used image2 instead of unrolled2 size), I'll update the answer.

Comment: removing the black region by first detecting the inner and outer circle part (or minimum and maximum radius) would be better, yes!

Comment: if template matching isn't to your liking, you can do a convolution (same thing but different). since the images are periodic along one axis anyway, that even suits the fourier transform. convolution using FFT has the advantage of lower time complexity, meaning probably faster for larger pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same idea but the correlation is done with a convolution (FFT) instead of `matchTemplate`. FFTs can be faster if there's much data.

Load inputs:

```py
im1 = cv.imread("circle1.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im2 = cv.imread("circle2.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
height, width = im1.shape
```

Polar transform (log polar as an exercise to the reader) with some arbitrary parameters that affect "resolution":

```py
maxradius = width // 2

stripwidth = maxradius
stripheight = int(maxradius * 2 * pi) # approximately square at the radius
#stripheight = 360

def polar(im):
    return cv.warpPolar(im, center=(width/2, height/2),
        dsize=(stripwidth, stripheight), maxRadius=maxradius,
        flags=cv.WARP_POLAR_LOG*0 + cv.INTER_LINEAR)

strip1 = polar(im1)
strip2 = polar(im2)
```

Convolution:

```py
f1 = np.fft.fft2(strip1[::-1, ::-1])
f2 = np.fft.fft2(strip2)
conv = np.fft.ifft2(f1 * f2)
```

minmaxloc:

```py
conv = np.real(conv) # or np.abs, can't decide
(i,j) = np.unravel_index(conv.argmax(), conv.shape)
i,j = (i+1) % stripheight, (j+1) % stripwidth
```

and what's that as an angle:

```py
print("degrees:", i / stripheight * 360)
# 42.401091405184175
```

https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/3da91f43324b0c53504d587a394d4c71

Comment: I think getting optimal fft size before doing convolution will make better performance (this post: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html).
I will try to convert this solution to Opencvsharp and compare/update the result asap. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you should do that by setting dsize in warpPolar, not by padding. in any case, I doubt it'll make much difference.