# detect defects which are grayish in color from the image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, detection

I need to detect the defects which are more grayish in color.
I have tried removing noise from the image, thresholding the image but due to gray color of the defect, it becomes invisible or only the boundary remains. I don't know how to detect the defects , if I apply dilation it gets mixed with the surrounding circles.
Images with defects:
[image]

Images without defect:

[image]

My original image with the red pen marked defect is :

[image]

I have tried the below code:

```
//convert to grayscale
    Mat gray_img;
    cv::cvtColor(r_img, gray_img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    
    Mat dst1, dst2, dst;
    cv::blur(gray_img, dst1, Size(3, 3));
    cv::blur(gray_img, dst2, Size(7, 7)); 
    cv::subtract(dst1, dst2, dst);

    //thresholding
    Mat thresh;
    adaptiveThreshold(dst, thresh, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 5, 5);

    Mat inv_thresh;
    bitwise_not(thresh, inv_thresh);
```

My thresholded image is

[image]

Comment: can you show the original image without red contour? Are there images of the same type of object without any defect, as well?

Comment: There is a discontinuity along the circle. You can unroll the circle by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360402/2393191 and afterwards search along each column for a strong gradient (really only in that direction). You will somehow have to ingore the border of the ring-like discontinuities in 90° to the circle direction, because your unrolling wont be pixel-perfect (and maybe your object isnt a perfect circle).

Comment: @Micka I have images with and without defects, both I edit the post

Comment: @Micka Can you explain me using the algorithm its a little bit confusing for me.